# Split ${fileBasename} in VS Code task

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am trying to automate a `curl` command in a VS Code task.

The full curl command without headers and auth should look something like:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:9000/schema/schemaName -d @schemaName-schema.json
```

Currently my task command looks like this:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:9000/schema/${fileBasename} -d @${fileBasename}
```

And fileBasename would be `schemaName-schema.json`

I want to split the fileBasename on the dash `-`, is this possible inside the VS Code command syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try if the snippet variable find replace also works for task variables

```
${fileBasename/^(.+?)-.*$/$1/}
```

Or you can use the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable)

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "echo some var",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "curl -X PUT http://localhost:9000/schema/${input:fileBasenamePart} -d @${fileBasename}",
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "fileBasenamePart",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.transform",
      "args": {
        "text": "${fileBasename}",
        "find": "^(.+?)-.*$",
        "replace": "$1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi rioV8,

The snippet variable find and replace results in an empty echo:
`"command": "echo ${fileBasename/^(.+?)-.*$/$1/}"`.

Your second options works like a charm. Thanks!